# Do you think what happens when a question becomes a "community question", is fair to the OP?

Tags: discussion, support, community-wiki, community-user

After the question of a person becomes "Community":

1. Who will receive points from subsequent up-votes? nobody.
2. Who has the ability to accept an answer? the original question-asker.

**Won't it be only fair if the answer to mentioned questions were as below?**

1. The Original Question Poster
2. The community

---

And my reasons are twofold:

1. The OP has triggered a wonderful high-quality question, so he
   deserves the credits and reputation.
2. A community, often times, can judge better than a single person.

Comment: Take time to formulate the question. Edit 1, Edit 2...avoid making it a chameleon question.

Comment: Voting to close as "Unclear" because between the rather vague initial question and the insistence on using "Edit" and "Edit 2" to clarify your question, you have just made it less clear.    Specifically, what do you mean by "transformation".  Are you asking about why it is fair questions get automatically converted to CW, or just converted to CW in general

Comment: @psubsee2003 ok, duely noted.

Comment: @Campiador your question still isn't very clear.  You are obviously concerned about something related to Community Wiki (but I'm not 100% positive since you tagged this [meta-tag:community-user] ).  It seems like you are asking a lot of follow-up questions to a question that you haven't asked.  **Why** are you asking, and what is your real concern?  Did you have a question of your own (or one you saw) that was converted to a CW post without your knowledge?

Comment: Questions no longer automatically become Community Wiki. This change was made in April. See [Putting the Community back in Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/). If a post was made CW since then it was either because a moderator made it that way (very rare, as far as I know), or the OP made it CW themselves.

Answer (score 8):

1. No-one.
2. The question-asker.

More in the FAQ: [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

As to the edited, changed version of your question: Yes, I think it's fair. The question-asker has every right to flag their question and ask for the community-wiki flag to be removed. If a moderator finds sufficient evidence to support the removal, they will do so. The reputation you gain on the Stack Exchange sites is just a gamified incentive. It's not the **purpose** of posting questions and answers.